# Visual Studio 2015 Script Error when launching the debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

When starting to debug a web application (MVC or Webforms, it doesn't matter), I get a bunch of Script Error pop-ups.

Line: 1087
Char: 13
Error: Unable to get property "addEventListener" of undefined or null reference.
Code: 0

URL: File:// ... /Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/CPUSampling/WebViews/Scripts/DiagnosticsHub.js

I also get the same error for the URL "File:// .. /WebViews/CpuView.html"

I have tried while troubleshooting:

1. Repaired my VS 2015 instance
2. Started the debugger without the Diagnostic Tools window visible

Any ideas on how to solve this would be appreciated!

Comment: still an issue in VS2019